# Can you help unlocking encrypted device LUKS (version 1) Running: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: mount, encryption

Having trouble accessing an encrypted volume. I'm certain of the password. The volume was initially created with Zorin, which I no longer have. I am currently trying to access this in a virtual machine.

Error unlocking encrypted device:

```
error unlocking /dev/sdb1: Failed to activate device: Operation not permitted (udisks-error-quark,0)
```

[image: screenshot]